# if we are tracking driver movement on map so we move marker, so does moving marker will be considered in same API call to render map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to track driver movement to do so I am moving marker as per the co-ordinates, so if we are changing marker position on map will there me more API call's as we change marker position

Answer (score 0):

No.

> User interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads.

https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#dynamic-maps